# Dropbox "No directories are being ignored" on RHEL

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, rhel, rhel8

Let me start by saying Dropbox support for Linux is in need of some serious improvement! It took me half a day to figure out how to install it on RHEL and that's just the command line interface (don't even know if there is a GUI).

Having it now installed, I'm finding that it doesn't appear to be work properly :( I'm using the recommended python controls and when I type

```
dropbox exclude add test_folder
```

it does remove the folder from the list. However, I can not get it back. When I check the exclusion list, it says "No directories are being ignored." Therefore, I can not add it back via `exclude remove`. I can see when I login online, the folder still exists, but I have no way of adding it back to my local machine.

Am I missing something?

```
Dropbox daemon version: 124.4.4912
Dropbox command-line interface version: 2020.03.04
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [forum over on Dropbox](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-files-folders/Can-t-un-exclude-directories-with-dropbox-py-exclude-remove-lt/td-p/529664/page/4), a solution was posted January 2022 by Walter@Dropbox and I can confirm it worked for me. Below I'm just quoting his solution for your convenience:

> Hi all - happy New Year!
>
> I checked back internally on this and I have an update for you.
>
> This should be fixed in our latest, stable version of the desktop app
> found [here](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-desktop-client-builds/Stable-Build-138-4-2392/td-p/565481).
>
> If you'd like to give our beta version a go instead, please download
> and install the app from [this page](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-desktop-client-builds/Beta-Build-139-3-4817/td-p/566970).
>
> Let us know how it goes!

Answer (score 2):

I'm bummed to find this question with no answers yet because I've been experiencing the same issue for a month or two now. My excluded folders no longer appear in my exclude list, so even though they exist in the cloud, I can't get them back locally. The only (unsatisfactory) solution I've found so far is to completely remove the Dropbox application, daemon, and nautilus extension and reinstall it all. But again, if I then add something to the exclude list that I want to remove later, I can't do it.

EDIT: It looks like there's a discussion on the official Dropbox forum [here](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-files-folders/Can-t-un-exclude-directories-with-dropbox-py-exclude-remove-lt/m-p/529664) that doesn't yet have any solutions.

Comment: I can confirm as of 20th December 2021 - same problem, still no movement by Dropbox to resolve this bug. Simplest workaround is to Unlink from Dropbox console and then relink which wipes the selective sync list and you can start again. It's not a great workaround.